# Bootstrap clock renders badly on android chrome?

Tags: html, css

So I'm using this on my website:

HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-spin fa-4x fa-clock-spin x1"></i>
```

CSS:

```
.x1 {
    font-size: 3vw !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 41.5%;
    left: 48.2%;   
}
```

and on my S6/S5, the clock spins (not only the lines inside it) and a part of it is missing. The photo on pc, everything works fine. Why does that happen?

[image]

Comment: Make sure your browser is up-to-date.

Comment: This isn't the problem. The android browser does the same, and on S5 this still happens.

Comment: Android browser is based on Chrome's rendering engine. It's unclear to me what "S5" you're talking about.

Comment: Samsung galaxy s5

Comment: try adding **width** to **.x1**

Comment: @Sonia still doesn't work

Comment: This happens only in Chrome, firefox renders it correctly.